# Looking for ANPR/LPR (Automatic Number Plate Recognition/License Plate Recognition) SDK for android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am looking for ANPR/LPR (Automatic Number Plate Recognition/License Plate Recognition) SDK for android..Is there any SDK for Android?

i want to develop a license plate identification software for android , where users can scan a plate using phone camera and identify the number.

i tried some optical character recognition(OCR) engines like Tesseract, but the accuracy is so bad.

is there any method I can use but OCR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too am working on ANPR's. I think just using an OCR might not help.
The opensource project [Javananpr](http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/) helped me a lot to understand the challenges and how one can tackle them. I suggest you to read the documentation there and maybe it can give you some direction.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same use case at my end.I tried to use tessert act to recognize the image into character but it fails most of the time to recognize. I need your suggestion to use the better api for reading number plates with android dev environment.

Answer (score 6):

Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com)

It's a C++ library that uses OpenCV and Tesseract.  It should be possible to run this on Android via JNI.

Comment: it now has already frameworks for iOS, Android, etc.

Comment: Have tried this solution but not works on more than 70% accuracy in my case in my Country. Any suggestion?

Comment: You might have to tune the system based on your country's number plate format.